# HttpRequestException while executing BlobClient.UploadAsync

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk

I have following code to upload files to my Azure storage:

Read File Stream like below:

```
   FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
```

and pass to the function =>

```
 public async Task<Response<BlobContentInfo>> UploadBlob(string containerName, string blobName, Stream stream, string contentType,
            IDictionary<string, string> metadata = null)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> metadataEncoded = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (metadata != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in metadata)
                {
                    string encodedValue = TextUtilities.Base64Encode(keyValuePair.Value);
                    metadataEncoded.Add(keyValuePair.Key, encodedValue);
                }
            }
            await using (stream)
            {
                BlobClient blobClient = GetBlobClient(containerName, blobName);
                BlobHttpHeaders httpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = contentType };
                BlobRequestConditions conditions = new BlobRequestConditions();
                Response<BlobContentInfo> uploadAsync = await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, httpHeaders, metadataEncoded, conditions);
                stream.Close();
                return uploadAsync;
            }
        }
```

If I try to upload arbitrary files like this sample pdf => http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf it works fine. But for some reason if I try to upload pdf files like in this page =>
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/
[Dot.NET Core Documentation PDF](https://opdhsblobprod02.blob.core.windows.net/contents/c6aea4f5457448ee818b7292ba695982/7da2902de973f0e7658c252ce07c16ae?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=%2BsacpAI5GdZhGu0f2KlIx6Tgw8JVxFlMWRwSngC5j%2Bk%3D&st=2020-01-11T06%3A53%3A24Z&se=2020-01-12T07%3A03%3A24Z&sp=r)

I am receiving following exception:

```
Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.

Inner Exception 2:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..

Inner Exception 3:
SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
```

I don't think this is related to file size, because I also tried some other .pdf files with larges sizes, and they got pushed to Azure Storage.

Am I missing something specific here? I also downloaded the .pdf from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/ and received same error from the line `await blobClient.UploadAsync()`

Note: As a reference I found this open GitHub issue, but not resolved yet.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/9212

Comment: Will it be possible to include a link to the PDF that you're not able to upload? Your 2nd link just points to the .Net Core documentation page.

Comment: The is a download link on the left bottom of the page.

Answer (score 6):

I have also stuck with this issue. Its solution is very simple, just set your stream position as 0.

stream.Position = 0;

All set, it will work.

Comment: Hi Deepak, welcome to SO! Please read up on [writing a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before you answer your next question! Enjoy your stay :)